# Change the color of a button(s) for a duration of time

Tags: vb.net, button, timer

I have a small VB.net app that has a LOT of buttons. I need to change the back color of the buttons when they are clicked and then set it back to its original color after a duration of 10 seconds. I am struggling with either using a timer or the time process both of which have their own issues.

Any ideas to make this work and work efficiently?

Code:

```
Private Sub MyButtons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles Button1.Click,
Button2.Click

    Dim myButton = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    MakeCall()
    myButton.BackColor = Color.Green
    'TurnOnActiveCallCOLOR.Enabled = True
    For i As Integer = 0 To 10000 - 1
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
    Next
    myButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64)
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you're making it sleep for ten seconds 9999 times.

Comment: Yeah I got rid of that, as it wasn't working correctly.

Comment: I would think for this task a Windows Forms Timer would be more then sufficient.

Comment: @NoAlias : It executes for 0 as well, so it is even 10000 times. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the use of [**lambda expressions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions) (and a lookup table if you want to interact with it further) you can do this pretty easily:

```
'Lookup table for if you want to be able to interact with the timers even more.
Dim ButtonTimers As New Dictionary(Of Button, Timer)

Private Sub MyButtons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click
    MakeCall()

    Dim myButton = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    myButton.BackColor = Color.Green

    'If a timer already exists for the button, restart it.
    Dim existingTimer As Timer = Nothing
    If ButtonTimers.TryGetValue(myButton, existingTimer) Then
        existingTimer.Stop()
        existingTimer.Start()
        Return 'Do not execute the rest of the code.
    End If

    'Create the timer and set its Interval to 10000 ms (10 seconds).
    Dim buttonTimer As New Timer() With {.Interval = 10000}

    'Add a handler to its Tick event.
    AddHandler buttonTimer.Tick, _
        Sub(tsender As Object, te As EventArgs)
            myButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64)

            'Dispose timer and remove from lookup table.
            ButtonTimers.Remove(myButton)
            buttonTimer.Stop()
            buttonTimer.Dispose()
        End Sub

    ButtonTimers.Add(myButton, buttonTimer)
    buttonTimer.Start()
End Sub
```

If you want to interact with a button's timer (if one exists) you can do:

```
Dim buttonTimer As Timer = Nothing
If ButtonTimers.TryGetValue(yourButtonHere) Then
    'Do something with buttonTimer...
End If
```

Comment: So does this handle if multiple buttons are clicked simultaneously so they get their "own event" handler?

Comment: When trying your code, I get the following error: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'TESTProject.Form1' to type 'System.ComponentModel.IContainer'.'

On line:
`Dim buttonTimer As New Timer(Me) With {.Interval = 10000}`

Comment: @FNDevCJ : Yes, each button gets their own timer. As for the error try changing the line to: `Dim buttonTimer As New Timer() With {.Interval = 10000}` (remove `Me`). I wrote the code from my phone so I was in no position test it.

Comment: @FNDevCJ : I updated my code to reflect the change and I also added so that it restarts a timer if one exists when a button is pressed the second time.

Comment: Also, can the downvoter please explain what could possibly be bad about my answer, that is not with the others'?

Comment: @FNDevCJ : Sadly, yes. Glad all of us could help though! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of using a Windows Forms Timer to accomplish what you need:

```
Private MyButton As Button

Private Sub MyButtons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click
   MyButton = DirectCast(sender, Button)
   MyButton.BackColor = Color.Green

   Timer1.Enabled = True

   MakeCall()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
   MyButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64)
   Timer1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Good solution :)! Though bare in mind that this only works for one button at a time.

Comment: @VisualVincent Agreed, I was just keeping the solution as simple as I could.

Comment: UPDATE: When testing on simultaneous buttons, only the last one changes back to original color.

Answer (score 2):

To handle an arbitrary number of buttons, you could have something like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim buttonTimers As New Dictionary(Of Control, ButtonTimer)

    Class ButtonTimer
        Property Timeout As Integer = 2000
        Property Target As Control
        Property ActiveColor As Color = Color.Green
        Property DefaultColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64)

        Private tim As Timer

        Sub TimTick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            tim.Stop()
            Target.BackColor = DefaultColor
        End Sub

        Sub New()
            ' empty constructor
        End Sub

        Sub New(target As Control)
            Me.Target = target
            Me.Target.BackColor = Me.ActiveColor
            tim = New Timer With {.Interval = Timeout}
            AddHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf TimTick
            tim.Start()

        End Sub

        Sub Restart()
            Target.BackColor = Me.ActiveColor
            If tim IsNot Nothing Then
                tim.Stop()
                tim.Start()
            End If
        End Sub

        Public Sub DisposeOfTimer()
            If tim IsNot Nothing Then
                tim.Stop()
                RemoveHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf TimTick
                tim.Dispose()
            End If

        End Sub

    End Class


    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click
        Dim myButton = DirectCast(sender, Button)

        'MakeCall()

        If buttonTimers.ContainsKey(myButton) Then
            buttonTimers(myButton).Restart()
        Else
            buttonTimers.Add(myButton, New ButtonTimer(myButton))
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        For Each x In buttonTimers
            x.Value.DisposeOfTimer()
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

If a button is clicked again before the timeout, the time is restarted.

You can add other constructors if you want to have a different timeout/colours for different buttons.

The `MyBase.FormClosing` code should be included in your form closing handler (if there is one) so that the timers are cleaned up properly.

I expect it would be tidier overall to make your own custom button class which inherits from Button, so you might want to investigate doing that. ([How to: Inherit from Existing Windows Forms Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-inherit-from-existing-windows-forms-controls).)

Comment: Very nice answer! I like how each one of us takes our answer one step further ;). I actually considered creating custom classes for my solution, but I thought it might be a bit overkill.

Comment: @VisualVincent I agree: it's one of those things where you start doing it and think "I could add a bit here" and "well, might as well make that a property" and "I'll just tweak this..." and by the time you're done someone else has answered, been accepted, and no-one else ever sees what you've done haha.

Comment: So true! Though right now the OP has unaccepted, so you still have a chance of getting it! -- I wrote a _**really**_ extensive answer once that were to address a certain type of question that people ask every now and then (thought it might be a good way to start closing the new questions as duplicates), by the time I was done a shorter answer (with only one or two minor examples) had been written and accepted. To this day no one seems to have seen it ;). The OP acknowledged it, but didn't have the reputation to upvote.

Comment: I wish I could accept all the answers. You all provide great responses. It would be nice to accept as a working solution, or a working solution with caveats, etc.

Answer (score 2):

asynh and await if you don't want use timer. Simple method using task.delay

```
Private Async Sub ButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click
    DirectCast(sender, Button).BackColor = Color.Red 'after click setcolor to red
    Await setColorAfterDelay(sender) 'Add this comand on button click and don't forget add asynh before sub in this method
End Sub

Public Async Function setColorAfterDelay(sender As Object) As Task
    Await Task.Delay(1000) ''Milisecound how long you wana dealey
    DirectCast(sender, Button).BackColor = Color.White 'and set colorto white
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be done better by dynamically creating timer controls so each button has it's own timer but here is what I came up with.

> Oh, an set your timer to 1000 interval and enabled to 'False'.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim T1 As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        T1 = T1 + 1
        If T1 = 10 Then
            For Each button In Controls
                button.backcolor = Color.FromArgb(225, 225, 225)
            Next
            Timer1.Stop()
            T1 = 0
        End If
        Me.Text = T1
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Red
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Button2.BackColor = Color.Orange
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Button3.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Button4.BackColor = Color.Green
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Button5.BackColor = Color.Blue
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```